# How can I find out what era a block was produced in?

Tags: sidecar, substrate-api-sidecar

Question on using the Substrate Sidecar API. I'm trying to get the current "era" a block is in. Looking through the API endpoints it's not clear which one would give me that. The "blocks/head" endpoint has an "era" field however it's only for extrinsics and their life span. I'm looking for something like how this [website](https://polkastats.io/block?blockNumber=11000000) displays it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the documentation for all Substrate API Sidecar endpoints [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-api-sidecar/dist/).

For the information you're looking for, you can use the `/pallets/staking/progress` endpoint. By default, this will look up the latest block, but you can also pass in a historical block as a query param `...?at=<blockNumber>`. The value you are looking for will be found in the "activeEra" key.

Here is a snipped example of the object returned from `/pallets/staking/progress?at=11000000`:

```
{
    "at": {
        "hash": "0x7fae32d478e996a90f0cad3ce0ac4b642b6d794c394bec0de4b9a10038fc924a",
        "height": "11000000"
    },
    "activeEra": "761", <--- What you're looking for

   /*-SNIP-*/
}
```